# Open3d: How to update point cloud during window running?

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d-reconstruction, open3d

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to visualize 3d point cloud from disparity map. It works perfectly with one map.

**ISSUE**

I want to update what's in window. When I call run() method new thread is opened and I cannot do anything till the window will be closed. I'd like to clear what's in window and display new cloud **without closing the window**, so it would be something like animation.

**CODE**

I've created Visualizer object and I do everything on that.

```
    vis = open3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    cloud = open3d.io.read_point_cloud(out_fn) # out_fn is file name
    vis.add_geometry(cloud)
    vis.run()
```

Answer (score 5):

The class open3d.visualization.Visualizer has .update_geometry() and .remove_geometry() function you can use to achieve that.
Another way around you can try is using open3d.visualization.VisualizerWithKeyCallback class.

```
vis = o3d.visualization.VisualizerWithKeyCallback()
cloud = open3d.io.read_point_cloud(out_fn)
vis.create_window()
vis.register_key_callback(key, your_update_function)
vis.add_geometry(cloud)
vis.run()

def your_update_function():
    #Your update routine
    vis.update_geometry(cloud)
    vis.update_renderer()
    vis.poll_events()
    vis.run()
```

Comment: Please see http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/visualization/customized_visualization.html#callback-functions. There  should be no need to update vis in callback functions.