# Open3D - C++: how to animate 3D point cloud

Tags: c++, animation, open3d

In Open3D, with **C++**, how to animate 3D point cloud: same question that this one in python [Open3d: How to update point cloud during window running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112433/open3d-how-to-update-point-cloud-during-window-running) but can't get this to work.

The following code (inspired from github repo example `examples/cpp/PointCloud.cpp`) compile, run (the viewer and point appears), but animation is not rendered

```
>> cat ../examples/cpp/PtCloud.cpp 
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "open3d/Open3D.h"

#include <unistd.h> // sleep

using namespace open3d;

void PrintPointCloud(const std::shared_ptr<geometry::PointCloud> &pointcloud) {
    using namespace open3d;

    bool pointcloud_has_normal = pointcloud->HasNormals();
    utility::LogInfo("Pointcloud has %d points.",
                     (int)pointcloud->points_.size());

    Eigen::Vector3d min_bound = pointcloud->GetMinBound();
    Eigen::Vector3d max_bound = pointcloud->GetMaxBound();
    utility::LogInfo(
            "Bounding box is: ({:.4f}, {:.4f}, {:.4f}) - ({:.4f}, {:.4f}, "
            "{:.4f})",
            min_bound(0), min_bound(1), min_bound(2), max_bound(0),
            max_bound(1), max_bound(2));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < pointcloud->points_.size(); i++) {
        if (pointcloud_has_normal) {
            const Eigen::Vector3d &point = pointcloud->points_[i];
            const Eigen::Vector3d &normal = pointcloud->normals_[i];
            utility::LogInfo("{:.6f} {:.6f} {:.6f} {:.6f} {:.6f} {:.6f}",
                             point(0), point(1), point(2), normal(0), normal(1),
                             normal(2));
        } else {
            const Eigen::Vector3d &point = pointcloud->points_[i];
            utility::LogInfo("{:.6f} {:.6f} {:.6f}", point(0), point(1),
                             point(2));
        }
    }
    utility::LogInfo("End of the list.");
}

std::shared_ptr<geometry::PointCloud> pointcloud(new geometry::PointCloud);

bool AnimatePointCloud(visualization::Visualizer * visualizer) {
    if (!visualizer) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         sleep(2);
         pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 0.0, i+1.0));
         pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, i+1.0));
         pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 1.0, i+1.0));
         PrintPointCloud(pointcloud);
         visualizer->UpdateGeometry(pointcloud);
         visualizer->PollEvents();
         visualizer->UpdateRender();
         visualizer->Run();
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // 1. test basic pointcloud functions.

    pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    PrintPointCloud(pointcloud);

    // 2. test pointcloud visualization

    visualization::Visualizer visualizer;
    visualizer.CreateVisualizerWindow("Open3D", 1600, 900);
    visualizer.AddGeometry(pointcloud);
    visualizer.RegisterAnimationCallback(AnimatePointCloud);
    visualizer.Run();
    visualizer.DestroyVisualizerWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

The code is supposed to animate points that stack up in animated way: the viewer seems to freeze. Didn't find any C++ example. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues in your code:-

1. First of all, AFAIK the linked SO answer is incorrect. There is no need to update visualizer from callback functions, see [official docs](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/visualization/customized_visualization.html#callback-functions) for this. This probably will fix your problem. Also, official docs and linked answer are for python. In C++, you have less things to worry about, for example, no need to re-add geometry.
2. The new points generated are too far away to see and easily cross visualizer view port bounds. I have updated your code to only update once every second and new points are only one centimeter away.
3. **Do not add sleep in your code.** You are basically making visualizer thread sleep, hence the window becomes unresponsive.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <chrono>

#include "open3d/Open3D.h"

using namespace open3d;

std::shared_ptr<geometry::PointCloud> pointcloud(new geometry::PointCloud);

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
int pointsShiftFactor = 1;

bool AnimatePointCloud(visualization::Visualizer * visualizer) {
    if (!visualizer) return false;

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() > 1000000) {
        begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        pointsShiftFactor += 1;
        pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.01 * pointsShiftFactor));
        pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.01 * pointsShiftFactor));
        pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.01 * pointsShiftFactor));
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    pointcloud->points_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

    visualization::Visualizer visualizer;
    visualizer.CreateVisualizerWindow("Open3D", 1600, 900);
    visualizer.AddGeometry(pointcloud);
    visualizer.RegisterAnimationCallback(AnimatePointCloud);
    visualizer.Run();
    visualizer.DestroyVisualizerWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

Result -

[image: Open3d interactive visualization of animated pointcloud]